# python curve fit with multiple variables

Tags: python

I try to use python to fit some experimental data. After some research I found:
"You can pass curve_fit a multi-dimensional array for the independent variables, but then your func must accept the same thing. For example, calling this array X and unpacking it to x, y for clarity"
My function is:

```
def func(X, A, Ta, B, Tb, m, n):
     alpha,T = X
     return (((A * exp(-Ta/T)) + (B * exp(-Tb/T))) * ((alpha / 100) ** m)) * ((1 - (alpha / 100)) ** n

init_vals = [1000000, 10000, 10000000, 10000, 0.5, 0.8]
print(curve_fit(func, (alpha,T), dadt, p0=init_vals))
```

I tried some examples with different functions and it works. But with my function I get no results but lot of warnings:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  return (((A * exp(-Ta/T)) + (B * exp(-Tb/T))) * ((alpha / 100) ** m)) * ((1 - (alpha / 100)) ** n)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  return (((A * exp(-Ta/T)) + (B * exp(-Tb/T))) * ((alpha / 100) ** m)) * ((1 - (alpha / 100)) ** n)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    print(curve_fit(func, (alpha,T), dadt, p0=init_vals))
line 740, in curve_fit
    raise RuntimeError("Optimal parameters not found: " + errmsg)
RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1400.
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(X, a, b, c):
    x,y = X
    return np.log(a) + b*np.log(x) + c*np.log(y)

# some artificially noisy data to fit
x = np.linspace(0.1,1.1,101)
y = np.linspace(1,2, 101)
a, b, c = 10, 4, 6
z = func((x,y), a, b, c) * 1 + np.random.random(101) / 100


# initial guesses for a,b,c:
init_vals = [8, 2, 7]
best_vals = curve_fit(func, (x,y), z, p0=init_vals)
print(best_vals)

Comment: this i've found and there are no warnings

Comment: Update your question with this code. Don't add it in the comments...